# "Item not found" issue in keychain Access in ios10

Tags: ios

I am trying to retrieving the password from the keychain for iOS 10 app. But app is giving the error "**item not found**", which is working fine below version iOS 10 app.
Am i doing Anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This issue is happening for storing/retrieving the password in Keychain Access in iOS 10.
So use the "**keychain sharing**" capabilities for app as given in below image.

[image]